# Putting controls inside a notification in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

The Spotify Android app has music controls put in the notification (play/pause, next song).

I would like to let the user control a `Service` from a controls inside notification. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to make your own layout for Notification.

Can you try with below code.

First create an xml for your notification.

**custom_notification.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        style="Custom Notification Title" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        style="Custom Notification Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Now the java code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
        notification.contentView = contentView;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sunny is may you please show how to do on runtime with dynamic? Like can I create that RelativeLayout dynamically?

Comment: Hi Noitidart, You can do it by defining a container layout in XML and later on in Java file you can use LayoutInflater to inflate layout add it to container defined in XML file earlier.

Comment: Thanks very much Sunny I'm very new to Java so right now I'm just in the beginning stages of porting from Java to JNI may I ask a seperate question would you be ok with that? Thanks I know it's spoonfeeding but this is how I learn best.

Comment: Yes, write me on sunnyg28@gmail.com for any doubts.

Comment: Thanks @Sunny very much!

Answer (score 0):

[NotificationCompat.Builder.addAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

> Add an action to this notification. Actions are typically displayed by the system as a **button adjacent to the notification content**.
>   Action buttons won't appear on platforms prior to Android 4.1.

Comment: Is there any way to add something similar in versions below Android 4.1?

Comment: Looks like you have to create a custom notification layout.