# Dynamiclaly putting controls inside a notification in Android

Tags: android

As this topic does: [Putting controls inside a notification in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133180/putting-controls-inside-a-notification-in-android/23133356?noredirect=1#comment53721242_23133356)

I would like to do the same thing, but I want to dyanmically create my views. I don't have access to any xml I can't write relativelayout/imageview xml.

I am doing this via JNI on Firefox for Android so am still learning quite a bit. At this point I am only able to port from Java to JNI. I was wondering if you could please show me how to do do the same as the original topic but dynamically. This is what original topic does:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
        notification.contentView = contentView;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to do the same thing, but I want to dyanmically create my views. I don't have access to any xml I can't write relativelayout/imageview xml.

Then you cannot do what you want, strictly speaking. `RemoteViews` only defines what widgets and containers are inside of it via a layout resource file. The Java methods allow you to manipulate select properties of those widgets and containers, but you cannot add widgets and containers without layout resource files.

You are welcome to create "stub" layout resource files for different sorts of widgets and containers, then use the `RemoteViews` constructor to create `RemoteViews` for those widgets and containers, then use `addViews()` on `RemoteViews` to stitch those together into an arbitrary structure. This will be cumbersome and still may not allow you to achieve what you want.